# Javascript - xaxis range bar graph plotting?

Tags: bar-chart, x-axis

I was trying to plot set of values in graph using javascript. But the challenge is need to plot the values in the range in x-axis in a bar graph. How to tackle this challenge? Is there any graph libraries available for this in javascript? Your solutions will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

I tried using plotly and canvasjs graph  libraries but not worked as i expected.